# Dropoff library feature in SharePoint 2007

Tags: drop-off-library

Is dropoff library feature available in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. It was introduced in sharepoint 2010. You need to use custom solution in Sharepoint 2007.